# Problema vba excel 2010 funciona bien en modo paso a paso y no al ejecutar f5

Tags: excel, vba

Estimados, tengo el siguiente procedimiento para hacer etiquetas con `tbarcode` cuando lo ejecuto paso a paso o si elimino y vuelvo a agregar el objeto `tbarcode10` funciona ok, cuando lo ejecuto desde botón no. El mismo cuenta con un bucle para ir modificando los datos que arman los códigos de barra de la etiqueta.

La variable `i` es la que se va incrementando según las etiquetas a realizar, al finalizar el bucle deja actualizado el texto del *tbar*, pero no al momento de ir imprimiendo las etiquetas, siempre deja el mismo valor de la letra `i`, pese a que esta se va cambiando normalmente.

Aquí parte del procedimiento.

Podrían ayudarme? Gracias.

```
Do While i <= diferencia
 j = Format(Hoja1.txtfecha.Text, 0) + Format(Hoja1.cbproducto.Value, "00") + Format(Hoja1.txtcabeza.Text, "00") + Format(i, "0000")
 tbar.Text = j
 Hoja2.Cells(1, 1) = Hoja1.cbproducto.Text
 Hoja2.Cells(2, 2) = Hoja1.txtfechav.Text
 Hoja2.Cells(2, 3) = Hoja1.txtcabeza.Text
 i = i + 1
 Hoja2.PrintPreview
 Loop
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ME parece que tenes un problema.. pq el printpreview esta dentro del loop???? eso no detiene la ejecucion del codigo.. o si?

Comment: no deberia ser un problema

Comment: detiene el loop? o se sigue ejecutando el loop?

Comment: el loop se sigue ejecutando, al terminar el tbarcode deja el ultimo valor de la variable i, es decir termina correcto, ademas si le agrego un msgbox al tbarcode.text va mostrando bien con el cambio de valor de la variable

Comment: pero a hoja 2, cuando le pasas el valor de tbar?

Comment: Dim tbar As TBarCode10
 Set tbar = Sheets(2).TBarCode101

Comment: lo declaro de esta forma

Comment: y despues tbar.text= variable J que incluye la variable i

Comment: eso que comentaste (usa [edit] para agregar toda la info en la pregunta) es como obtienes el valor.. pero cuando se lo pasas devuelta a una celda?

Comment: no lo paso devuelta a una celda, imprimo la hoja2 donde esta insertado el tbarcode, mas otros datos, con la opcion hoja2.printout o printpreview, es decir a medida que el bucle va transcurriendo, cambia el valor del tbar segun la variable i y va imprimiendo la etiqueta de la hoja 2 hasta tanto salga del bucle